# Use PGP/Mime with Thunderbird and Enigmail

Tags: pgp, gnupg, enigmail

I would like to sign all my mail with my PGP key, and no matter if the recipient uses PGP or not, it should not confuse them. Last week I read a discussion that inline PGP is not good pratice, and I tend to agree. The advice was to use PGP/Mime. I use Thunderbird with Enigmail, and I try to set it to use PGP/Mime, but somehow it doesn't work.

In the **Enigmail Properties** I don't see any setting about PGP/Mime.

In the **Thunderbird Account Settings** I do see an option to use PGP/Mime for each account. I've checked these, but I don't see any change.

**How can I get this working? If this works, can I use HTML mail?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether to use PGP/MIME or inline signatures is an per-account setting in Enigmail. To change this option, open the *Account Settings*, and for each account you want to use PGP/MIME check the *Use PGP/MIME by default* box.

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: Well this is what I've done. I've checked those options already. Now if I write an email and send it, I get the message that the mail is composed in HTML and needs to be transformed to plain text. The result is inline PGP if I understand this correctly. This is all new to me, but I thought PGP/Mime meant that the signing of the mail was handled with an attachment. I don't see one.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem, also HTML mails are sent signed (Thunderbird 31, Enigmail 1.7.2). If you've got Enigmail installed you will _not_ see any attachment for the signature, have a look at the mail sources.

Comment: My mail gets converted to plain text, and when I send this to myself, the incoming message starts with `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----` - not what I would expect.

Comment: Did you make sure you haven't configured PGP/MIME for the wrong account or there are recipient rules enforcing inline PGP?

Comment: Well I see that if I compose a mail with the right (sender) account selected, I can choose account settings again and then PGP/Mime is unchecked. I checked that and now it does send in PGP/Mime format without further action. So that is good. Now I've got one other problem, which is that the mails I send to myself are displayed in plain text, while they do have HTML formatting. So the plaintext version of the mail is shown.

Comment: The image in your answer is different from when you write an email, and open the settings from that window.